# How to count up and broadcast a number in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a very basic site with a very basic idea: When an user connects to the website, it should say "Clicks: 0" and when he presses a button on his keyboard, it should do `clicks++` and update to "Clicks: 1" (assuming nobody has clicked).

I need to do this securely using NodeJS and Socket.io. I have the count function and it works, but I am not sure how I should store the amount of clicks. Normally I would do this in a database or some sort, then update it once in a while (updating it for every click will create a lot of load?).

## Socket update

```
socket.on("update", function() {
    $("#clicks").text(clicks++);
});
```

## jQuery emit

```
$("body, window").on("keyup", function() {
    socket.emit("update");
});
```

When I do this (assuming my `clicks` variable is defined), it will update across all clients. And it does.

What would be the best way to store the `clicks` variable? Obviously you need to do `clicks = database.get("clicks")` (if you know what I mean) when you launch the site initially. Thanks!

Comment: Primarily depends on dbms you will use for that. What database you mind to use?

Comment: @OlegMeleshko So you'd suggest using a database, then UPDATE the amount? First time using NodeJS, but I'm a ferm MySQL and MariaDB user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you prefer to use sql with nodejs, then there is a good solution for that - [Sequalize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)

There is a [way](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/?highlight=increment#incrementfields-options-promisethis) you can increment it just by using its instance method like this:

```
User.findById(1).then(function(user) {
  return user.increment('clicks', { by: 1 })
}).then(/* ... */);
```

**P.S:** `{ by: 1 }` is optional. More examples you may find [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#incrementing-certain-values-of-an-instance).

For [example](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findorcreate-search-for-a-specific-element-or-create-it-if-not-available):

```
var Clicks = sequelize.define('clicks', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true },
  amount: { type: Sequalize.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0 }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});

// Create table if not created yet
Clicks.sync();

// somewhere in your sockets callback
Clicks.findOrCreate({ where: { id: 1 }, defaults: { amount: 1 }})
      .spread(function(click, created) {
           if (created) {
              // created first time with default value, send some response back here
           } else {
             click.increment('amount', { by: 1 })
                .then(function() {
                    // send some response back to user(-s)
                });
           }
      });
```

Comment: So assuming I have no user-base and just have a table called "clickTable", would I just do: `clickTable.findById(1)` which would select the first row, then do the `increment('clicks'` would find the column called clicks and increment it? Is that how it's going to work? Obviously my clickTable needs to be defined etc.

Comment: @Snorlax Yes, it will. Just keep a record with an `id = 1` in this way. Table structure could be different, that's just an example with `findById`. There are many other ways you may store this info and query it then from your database. Sequalize is very flexible, just dig a bit deeper and you'll see.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how I should define what my table looks like. Does this look wrong? https://i.imgur.com/mQidQ8n.png - Table name is clicks and columns are id, clicks.

Comment: Sweet, I will go test it out asap. I need to type in my SQL password and so on. How would I go on about making it secure then? I don't mind people reading my code, as long as they can't read my database connection string.

Comment: Worked wonderfully. I had to add `timestamps: false` and a few other things, but it works perfectly! Thanks a lot, friend!